# Yii: findAllByAttributes() using $attributes vs $condition + $parms:

Tags: php, yii, sql-injection, yii1.x

I'd like to know is the first parameter of [`findAllByAttributes()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#findAllByAttributes-detail) can avoid SQL Injection, or only using `$condition` + `$params` have the protects from SQL Injection?

Any other considerations when you chose to use one of them?

[image]

---

Using `$attributes`:

```
$result = Setting::model()->findByAttributes(
   array(
       'name'=>$name,
       'lang_id'=>$lang_id
   )
);
```

Using `$condition` + `$parms`:

```
$result = Setting::model()->findByAttributes(
   '',
   'name =:name AND lang_id = :lang_id',
   array(
       ':name' => $name,
       ':lang_id' => lang_id
   )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `$attributes` in `findByAttributes()` protects you from SQL Injection, so this is perfectly safe:

```
$result = Setting::model()->findByAttributes([
    'name' => $name,
    'lang_id' => $lang_id,
]);
```

And this is usually preferred syntax, since it is simpler and shorter than prepared statements. But it does not cover all possible cases - it works for simple match, but for any operator different than `=` you need to use `$condition`:

```
$result = Setting::model()->findByAttributes(
    [
        'name' => $name,
        'lang_id' => $lang_id,
    ],
    'priority >= :priority',
    [':priority' => $priority]
);
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a great article about sql injection in Yii

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/275/how-to-write-secure-yii-applications/